# Supporting iOS 4.3 to iOS 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I already have the base code that supports ios 4.3 to ios 5. Now I would also like to support ios 6.0. 
The present base code has `modal views`, hard coded `CGRect's`, and rotation is different for each view. So I would like to know whether we can support ios 4.3 to ios 6.0 with the same base code, by just tweaking some changes, or do we need to create a complete new target?

Like we cannot use auto layout of ios 6.0 if I want to support previous versions as it will lead to a crash.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527517/what-is-the-best-way-for-supporting-both-screen-resolution-of-iphone4-and-iphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we can do this by setting up the Deployment Target to iOS 4.3. But then, why do you need to support iOS < 5.0 as around 85-90% of devices are on iOS 5.0+. See [this](http://insights.chitika.com/2012/ios-by-device/)

Also, when you set up support for iOS 4.3 or even iOS 5.1.1, you would have to handle multiple things. For example, the method for Orientation,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

isn't called for iOS 6. It is replaced by the methods,

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

You would need all the iOS versions on devices and then test each and every aspect of your app.

Comment: yeah, so is it a good idea to tweak the present target and make it compatible with all the versions? or create a new target altogether for ios 6.0?

Comment: You should consider making a single app compatible with all the versions of iOS. At the end of the day, you are not gonna upload a separate app for each iOS Version. Also, every app uploaded after iOS 6 release, needs support for iOS 6, so iOS 6 compatibility is compulsory.

Comment: hey, adding to that, so the method `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations &

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate`

will work fine in ios 4.3?

Comment: yes they won't be called in versions < iOS 6. so you would have to write both. - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 for versions < iOS 6 and - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate for iOS 6

Comment: It's the other way around: supportedInterfaceOrientations is for iOS6, the other two are for pre-iOS6.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xcode 4.5 it is perfectly valid to use one code base for building iOS 4.3 - 6.0 apps, but as always the key is testing on real iDevices with the given operating system versions.

Comment: exactly, so I am testing the app in simulator 5.0 it works fine, but for simulator 6.0 I am getting so many bugs. What is the best way to deal with that?

Comment: How do you deal with bugs in the rest of your development cycles? You find the location where you hit a brick wall and find a way through it, step by step. And you'll probably see that a fix to one bug clears out a lot others that relate to the same issue.
But again, there is nothing like testing on real iPhones and iPads and iPod Touches, I found out the hard way...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is perfectly fine and can be done to support ios 4.3 to ios 6.0 using the xcode 4.5.

And for the orientations in ios 6 have to do some work around like have to put some code differently as posted in **@Mayur J's answer.**

Or all you can do is just add categories for the required controller's like `UINavigationController`, `UIPopoverViewController`, `UIImagePickerViewController`, etc to return the supported orientation in ios 6.0 like below

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIPopoverController (UIPopoverController_Orientation)

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "UIPopoverController+UIPopoverController_Orientation.h"

@implementation UIPopoverController (UIPopoverController_Orientation)

-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
@end
```

Here I use `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape` as I only supports landscape orientations ie restrict my app to only landscape mode.

Hope this will help you.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: so this method will work fine for iOS 4.3 as well? Coz we had
   `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation` earlier. So if i put the above method, it will take care of both iOS 6 to iOS 4.3

Comment: yes works well as my app is also works fine on ios 4.3 for ipad